Why did C++03 allow data members with the same name as the class?
Between the C++98 standard and the C++03 standard, an interesting change was made:
struct S {
    int S;
};

This code is valid in C++03 and newer, but was ill-formed in C++98.
Specifically, [class.mem] paragraph 13 banned all data members from having the same name as the class in C++98, but this rule was relaxed so that if there is no user-declared constructor, you can have a non-static data member with the same name.
What is the motivation behind this?
What important use case is covered by this that would warrant revising the standard?

Why not? There is no collision potential here.

@Dúthomhas because any change to the standard needs to be sufficiently motivated and consume committee time, even benign editorial changes. It's almost never a question of "why not?", at least not when an international committee has to make an effort to revisit existing design. And fwiw, this rule is pretty obscure and quite surprising, seeing that you normally cannot have this name clash and the conditions in which it is allowed are very specific.

Perhaps the question is why was it limited in the first place? It broke compatibility with decades of C code.

Fair enough. Some of the committee’s time is spent fixing problems with the standard. I suspect that artificially forbidding a non-colliding name has ticked off a number of developers, and that concern made it back to the committee. But I would also be interested to know actual details.

This is from DR80.  To paraphrase, static was there originally to conform with C but between the May '96 and September '96 working papers the standard was changed and static was removed.  C++03 reverted that error from the language via the defect report.

If one does not follow the link, this not appear to answer the question.
